# Updating a state consisiting of an array of objects without mutation

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, reducers

If I have a state object like:

```
[{
   "value":"e1",
   "label":"john@example.com",
   "domain":"d1",
   "selected":false
},
{
   "value":"e2",
   "label":"jack@example.com",
   "domain":"d1",
   "selected":false
},
{
   "value":"e3",
   "label":"silvia@example.com",
   "domain":"d1",
   "selected":false
}]
```

and action object

```
{
    "value":"e1",
    "label":"john@example.com",
    "domain":"d1",
    "selected":false
}
```

in a redux reducer, how can I change in an action object 'selected' into true and update the state respectively without mutating it using preferably pure ES6 functions?

I am very new to Redux world and find it difficult to update state without mutating it.

Comment: There is a dedicated section in the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-an-item-in-an-array) for this which is really useful.

Comment: However, there is a problem in the state - which property is guaranteed to be an unique value ? i doubt `value` would be unique always

Comment: @ArshabhAgarwal value is unique. I am using the structure used by React Select which for some reason using value as a unique select option

Comment: @CodingIntrigue yeah that is what I was exactly looking for

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have sorted this myself long time ago but think it might be useful for others:

```
export const select = (state, action) => {

    const index = state.findIndex(elem => elem.value === action.payload.value);

    return [
        ...state.slice(0, index),
        {
            ...action.payload,
            selected: true
        },
        ...state.slice(index + 1)
    ];
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming there's a whole bunch of stuff in the current `state` and you want to change, in your array, the first object's `selected` value to `true` and then merge that with the current state and update the state.

Lets say your 'state object' is called `foo`, in your reducer function you will first do something like `foo[0].selected = true;` and then you can update the state using the spread operator with something like:

```
return {
  ...state,
  foo
};
```

I hope that makes some sense or maybe I'm way off the mark with what you're asking?

Comment: Before updating it I also need to reset the state fields all to 'selected':'false' without mutating it.